# Best practices for primary keys in partitioned fact tables in a data warehouse with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-design, partitioning, data-warehouse

I'm seeking advice on best practices regarding the implementation of partitioned tables in a data warehouse when using PostgreSQL. My current understanding is that partitioning a fact table by a timestamp column `time` makes sense since analytic queries often filter by time intervals. Semantically, it would be correct to have event_id as the primary key. However, PostgreSQL requires including the partitioning column in the primary key or unique constraints, leading to an error:

```
ERROR: unique constraint on partitioned table must include all partitioning columns
DETAIL: PRIMARY KEY constraint on table "earthquake_events" lacks column "time" which is part of the partition key.
```

If I opt to create a composite primary key including `event_id` and `time`, I face a new issue where dimension tables cannot reference just the `event_id` in the fact table due to the lack of a unique constraint that matches the given keys:

```
ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "earthquake_events"
```

This constraint would force me to create composite foreign keys that include both `event_id` and `time` in numerous dimension tables, which seems semantically incorrect and overly complex.

What is the recommended approach to designing primary keys and referencing foreign keys in partitioned fact tables in a DWH using PostgreSQL? Is there a better way to maintain the semantic integrity of the primary key while also adhering to PostgreSQL's partitioning requirements?

Thank you for your insights.

Comment: I haven't used PG partitioning since the native partitioning support was added, but when inheritance-based partitioning was standard, you generally just didn't get to have foreign-key checking that referenced a partitioned table. I'm hesitant to state this for a fact since I haven't verified it myself, but I don't see how you *could* have a foreign key using only the event_id - PG needs to verify that the associated row exists, and without also knowing the time, it wouldn't know which partition(s) to check, and a fallback of something like checking all partitions seems too slow to be feasible.

Comment: The FK in a fact table points to the primary key in the dimension table. it's unlikely that you have to partition the dimension table. Could you share some DDL? (in plain text, as an update to your question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to proceed in a data warehouse is *not* to create foreign keys. The data originate in a transactional database that guarantees referential integrity, and the ETL process shouldn't mess that up. Foreign keys not only don't work well with partitioned tables, they will also slow down data loading somewhat.